# Repeatable annotation not processed correctly by the JVM at Runtime

Tags: java

The JDK 14 on Windows 10 platform does not seem to process Repeatable annotation at the method level. In addition, the API call isAnnotationPresent() returns false when Repeatable annotations are in fact present. The following example demonstrates these behaviors.

The Color.java contains the declaration of a repeatable annotation and the Shirt class uses the annotation.
Color.java:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
 @Repeatable(Colors.class)
 @interface Color {
   String name();
 }
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
 @interface Colors {
   Color[] value();
 }
 @Color(name = "red") @Color(name = "blue") @Color(name = "green")
 class Shirt {
    //@Color(name = "red") @Color(name = "blue") @Color(name = "green")
     public void print(){
         System.out.println("The @repeatable annotation at the method level");
     }
 }
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestRepeatable {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testTypeWithIsAnnotationPresent();
        testTypeWtihoutIsAnnotationPresent();
        testMethodWithIsAnnotationPresent();
        testMethodWithoutIsAnnotationPresent();
    }

    public static void testTypeWithIsAnnotationPresent() {
        boolean flag;
        System.out.println("Processing testTypeWithIsAnnotationPresent() method..... ");
        System.out.println();
        String colorClassName = Color.class.getSimpleName();
        String shirtClassName = Shirt.class.getSimpleName();
        Class<Shirt> obj = Shirt.class;

        flag = obj.isAnnotationPresent(Color.class);
        if (flag) {
            System.out.println("The " + colorClassName + " annotation is present at the TYPE level in " + shirtClassName + " class");
            Color[] colorArray = Shirt.class.getAnnotationsByType(Color.class);
            for (Color color : colorArray) {
                System.out.println(color.name());
            }
            System.out.println("Test completed successfuly");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no "+colorClassName+" annotations declared at the TYPE level in "
                                +shirtClassName+ " class");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }//testTypeWithIsAnnotationPresent()

    public static void testTypeWtihoutIsAnnotationPresent() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Processing testTypeWtihoutIsAnnotationPresent().....");
        System.out.println("In this scenario, the system is not calling the API call \"isAnnotationPresent()\"");
        Color[] colorArray = Shirt.class.getAnnotationsByType(Color.class);
        for (Color color : colorArray) {
            System.out.println(color.name());
        }
    }//testTypeWtihoutIsAnnotationPresent()

    public static void testMethodWithIsAnnotationPresent() {
        System.out.println("Processing testMethodWithIsAnnotationPresent() method..... ");
        System.out.println();
        String colorClassName = Color.class.getSimpleName();
        String shirtClassName = Shirt.class.getSimpleName();
        Class<Shirt> obj = Shirt.class;
        Method[] method = obj.getDeclaredMethods();
        int length = method.length;
        if (length < 1) {
            System.out.println("The are not methods declared in " + shirtClassName + " class");
        }//outter if
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (method[i].isAnnotationPresent(Color.class)) {
                    Annotation annotation = method[i].getAnnotation(Color.class);
                    Color c = (Color) annotation;
                 //additional code needed here to process the annotations
                }// inner if
                else {
                    System.out.println("The " + method[i].getName() + " method in " + shirtClassName
                            + " class does not have any annotation of type " + colorClassName);
                    continue;
                }// inner else
            }//for
        }// outter else
    }//testMethodWithIsAnnotationPresent()

    public static void testMethodWithoutIsAnnotationPresent() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("In testMethodWithoutIsAnnotationPresent()");
        Class<Shirt> obj = Shirt.class;
        Method[] method = obj.getDeclaredMethods();
        int length = method.length;
        if (length < 1) {
            System.out.println("The are no methods declared in " + Shirt.class.getSimpleName() + " class");
        }//outter if
        else {
            System.out.println("There are " + length + " methods present in class " + Shirt.class.getSimpleName());
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Annotation annotation = method[i].getAnnotation(Color.class);
                Color c = (Color) annotation;
                if (c == null) {
                    System.out.println("No annotations at the method level");

                } else {
                    System.out.print("The annotation for " + method[i].getName() + "is " + Color.class.getSimpleName());
                    System.out.println("With name " + c.name());
                }
            }//for
        }
    }//testMethodWithoutIsAnnotationPresent()
}// end
```

First, run the TestRepeatable and observe the output. The first method “testTypeWithIsAnnotationPresent()” uses the API call “isAnnotationPresent()” to determine if Color annotations used at the TYPE level in the Shirt Class (which they are) the API call returns false. I am not sure why?
The second method “testTypeWtihoutIsAnnotationPresent()” doesn’t use the API call “isAnnotationPresent()” and simply uses “getAnnotationsByType()” and prints the details which works as expected.
Run the TestRepeatable for the second time but modify the Color.java as follow:
This is the modified Color.java:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
 @Repeatable(Colors.class)
 @interface Color {
   String name();
 }
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 //@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
 @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
 @interface Colors {
   Color[] value();
 }
 //@Color(name = "red") @Color(name = "blue") @Color(name = "green")
 class Shirt {
     @Color(name = "Cyan") @Color(name = "Pink") @Color(name = "Yellow")
     public void print(){
         System.out.println("The @repeatable annotation at the method level");
     }
 }
```

In this scenario, the third method in the TestRepeatable class  “testMethodWithIsAnnotationPresent()” interrogates the “print()” method declaration for the presence of the @Color annotations (which there are 3 of them present) by using the API call isAnnotationPresent(), however, call returns false and again I don’t know why?

In the last scenario, the method testMethodWithoutIsAnnotationPresent() doesn’t use the API call isAnnotationPresent(), instead, it tries to get the Color annotations from the Method object (and there are 3 of them) but does not find any annotations.

In summary, maybe the code is behaving correctly and my understanding of @Repeatable annotations is off or perhaps it is the other way around. Any explanation would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe; please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. That being said, the behavior you see with the method is the correct behavior. See [§9.7.5 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.5): "_If a declaration context or type context has **multiple annotations of a repeatable annotation type `T`**, then it is **as if the context has no explicitly declared annotations of type `T`** and one implicitly declared annotation of the containing annotation type of `T`_" (**emphasis** added).

Comment: @Slaw: I added the example code (thanks for any feed back)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Repeatable Annotations

Here's an excerpt from [§9.7.5 Multiple Annotations of the Same Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.5)  of the *Java Language Specification* (JLS):

> If a declaration context or type context has multiple annotations of a repeatable annotation type `T`, then it is as if the context has no explicitly declared annotations of type `T` and one implicitly declared annotation of the containing annotation type of `T`.
>
> The implicitly declared annotation is called the *container annotation*, and the multiple annotations of type `T` which appeared in the context are called the *base annotations*. The elements of the (array-typed) `value` element of the container annotation are all the base annotations in the left-to-right order in which they appeared in the context.

What this means is that if you have the following annotations:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Repeatable(FooContainer.class)
public @interface Foo {

  String value();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface FooContainer {

  Foo[] value();
}
```

Then this:

```java
// Important: There's more than one of the repeatable annotation
@Foo("baz")
@Foo("qux")
public class Bar {}
```

Is actually compiled as if the following was written:

```java
@FooContainer({@Foo("baz"), @Foo("qux")})
public class Bar {}
```

In other words, the `Bar` class does not have any `@Foo` annotations present. The present annotation is `@FooContainer` which has an array element holding the `@Foo` annotations—making the `@Foo` annotations "indirectly present". You can see this by inspecting the array returned by `#getAnnotations()`. You can also see this when looking at the output of `javap`:

```
SourceFile: "Bar.java"
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #17(#18=[@#19(#18=s#20),@#19(#18=s#21)])
    @FooContainer(
      value=[@Foo(
        value="baz"
      ),@Foo(
        value="qux"
      )]
    )
```

Note that although this answer has focused on class annotations, the same behavior is seen for method annotations.

---

## Reflection and Repeatable Annotations

Here's the Javadoc of [`AnnotatedElement#isAnnotationPresent(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#isAnnotationPresent(java.lang.Class)):

> Returns true if an annotation for the specified type is *present* on this element, else false. This method is designed primarily for convenient access to marker annotations.
>
> The truth value returned by this method is equivalent to: `getAnnotation(annotationClass) != null`

As explained previously, the repeatable annotation is not present when it's wrapped in its container annotation. The [`AnnotatedElement#getAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotations()) method has the same behavior; it returns the *present* annotations but not *indirectly present* nor *associated* annotations. The class Javadoc of [`AnnotatedElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html) explains what it means for an annotation to be *present*, *associated*, and so on.

The Javadoc of [`AnnotatedElement#getAnnotationsByType(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html#getAnnotationsByType(java.lang.Class)) says:

> Returns annotations that are *associated* with this element. If there are no annotations *associated* with this element, the return value is an array of length 0 [zero]. **The difference between this method and `getAnnotation(Class)` is that this method detects if its argument is a *repeatable annotation type* (JLS 9.6), and if so, attempts to find one or more annotations of that type by "looking through" a container annotation** [*emphasis added*]. The caller of this method is free to modify the returned array; it will have no effect on the arrays returned to other callers.

The emphasized part explains why this method can find your repeated annotation.

So if all you want to know is if one or more of a repeatable annotation is present/associated then I believe this is the most concise approach:

```java
boolean hasFoo = Bar.class.getAnnotationsByType(Foo.class).length != 0;
```

---

## Your Code

Small note about your code: Your `@Color` annotation has a retention policy of `CLASS` (the default) whereas your `@Colors` annotation has a retention policy of `RUNTIME`. While this setup is perfectly legal, I consider it strange. It can also be confusing. If you have only one `@Color` you won't be able to query it using reflection, but if there's more than one `@Color` you *will* be able to query them using reflection via the implict `@Colors`. In my opinion, it's best to have the same retention policy for both the repeatable annotation and the container annotation.

Comment: Thank you Slaw, my code works correctly now. As you pointed out, I change the parameter in the isAnnotationPresent() API call from the annotation class to the annotation container class per the JSL 9.7.5. Thanks again for the pointer.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer solved your question then please consider accepting it in order to mark this question as solved. Also, be careful with using `isAnnotationPresent(Class)` to test for the container annotation; as pointed out, if you have only one of the repeatable annotation it _will not_ be implicitly wrapped in its container annotation.

Comment: <<If you have only one of the repeatable annotation it will not be implicitly wrapped in its container annotation>> Oh, thanks for the heads up, I have to modify the code to account for that.